# HTTP 403 (Forbidden)

Tags: lua, webhooks, roblox

I was making a ban UI for my game and I wanted to make it log the bans to my discord server, however I got the error "HTTP 403 (Forbidden)"
Here's the part where it sends the message:

```
local url = "https://discord.com/api/webhooks/1102608853352337489/EN1GHsmDmZ5EaYgVBWxi2N4avghed1lfqkGVxUscUbOlg0a925iexpKKYu8zNirodNg4" 
            local http = game:GetService("HttpService")
            local data = {
                    ['embeds'] = {{
                        ['title'] = "**User banned**",
                    ['description'] = "**"..Player.Name.."**".." has been banned for the reason: **"..playerData[2].."** Slaps: **"..slaps.."**"

                    }}
                }

                local finaldata = http:JSONEncode(data)
                http:PostAsync(url, finaldata)
```

Answer (score 0):

check if you have HTTP Settings on. Go to home, then game setting, permission, and turn on HTTP Requests. Let me know if that helps!

Comment: it's already on